# Whats the meaning of " gNewSense is based on Ubuntu"?

Tags: custom-distributions

I am beginner to Linux and I am learning this.

Now I actually unable to understand when someone says that this distribution is based on this particular kernel. For eg. gNewSense id based on Ubuntu or Ubuntu is based on Debian etc.

So Can anyone please tell what does this statement exactly means??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that Ubuntu developers took Debian, added their tweaks and changes and called this Ubuntu. In turn, gNewSense developers took Ubuntu, added their tweaks and changes and called this "gNewSense". You or me, in turn, can take gNewSense, add something new and make another distribution.

Al of them - Debian, Ubuntu and gNewSense - are Linux *distributions*, i.e. collections of software based around Linux kenel and GNU software.